# Running Spring Boot Application.main() via IntelliJ doesn't find my local profile

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I've been running my Spring Boot (2.1.0) app via Gradle `bootRun` but since adding in the Actuator, this causes the app to not actually shutdown when I tell IntelliJ to stop the app. For whatever reason, this is only an issue when running in Debug mode.

The solution I found online was to just run the Application.main() but now, my local profile isn't being picked up. So I have the typical `application.yml` along with various other profiles. All of the developers have an `application-local.yml` that is sitting at the root of the project and is ignored by git. Running Gradle's `bootRun` with `local` as the active profile works. But running `Application.main()` with the `local` active profile does not pick up the `application-local.yml` file's config.

[image]

As you can see in the image, I've not only specified the profile in Intellij's Active profiles section, but also as a VM option just like I do when running via Gradle.

Comment: spring-boot log prints which profile is active at the time of start-up, are you seeing that `local` is the active profile set?

Comment: Yes, it prints local, as I'd expect.

Comment: I'm seeing this same behavior. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

One more thing which you can try

Set `spring.profiles.active=local` in Environment Variables below VM Options